# Google Fonts won't work when imported at a less nested level.

Tags: css, google-font-api

I'm using Google Fonts, and have imported it in *less*. Here is my code:

main.less

```
#container {
  @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300);
  .like {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  }
}
```

This doesn't work. but if I put `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300);` before `#container`, it does.

I'm guessing this maybe because of path, but I don't know why. How do I fix this?

Comment: "Your `@imports` must come before all other content in your CSS. And I mean all of your content. Even putting comments before the `@import` tag will cause your imports to fail. So be sure to do your imports before you do anything else." - http://www.cssnewbie.com/css-import-rule/#.UtNj1PQmnn8

Comment: Thanks! But is it necessary? if I put some other css rules before `@import`, I find it works too.

Comment: I'm quite sure it isn't working. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/setek/5QsvU/ this demonstrates that when `@import` is not the first line of a stylesheet/embed, it does not work. Try switching the two CSS lines around, you can see what happens.

Comment: Setek - I'd put that in as an answer if I were you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Your @imports must come before all other content in your CSS. And I mean all of your content. Even putting comments before the @import tag will cause your imports to fail. So be sure to do your imports before you do anything else." - http://www.cssnewbie.com/css-import-rule/#.UtNj1PQmnn8

Direct from W3C:

"Any `@import` rules must precede all other at-rules and style rules in a style sheet (besides `@charset`, which must be the first thing in the style sheet if it exists), or else the `@import` rule is invalid." - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#at-import

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/setek/5QsvU/

This demonstrates that when @import is not the first line of a stylesheet/embed, it does not work. Try putting the `@import` first line, you can see what happens:

```
#sidebar a { color: #f00; }

@import url('http://jsfiddle.net/css/screen.css?jobofferinsidebar');
```

vs. just having:

```
@import url('http://jsfiddle.net/css/screen.css?jobofferinsidebar');
```

Comment: @callblueday that's fine, it's the `@import` declaration that must be before all other code. The `font-family` can exist anywhere. Just make sure the `@import` is at the top.

Comment: Thanks so much! Here is my code, I use `less`.

    @base-img: "@{base-url}img/";
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300);
    #container {
      .like {
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
      }
    }

And it works. I think it also follows the rule. `@base-img: "@{base-url}img/";` isn't an actual css rule.