# Social Icon web font loads in codepen, but not in local tresting OR online?

Tags: html, css, icons

Here's my pen:

http://codepen.io/MarcMurray/pen/cCdBu

And here's my page:

http://daraghkane.bcfedigitalmedia.com/moh/

For some reason the font refuses to load locally or online outside of codepen, I have a feeling it may be something to do with this part of my CSS:

```
@import url (..)
/* entypo */
[class*="entypo-"]:before
```

But I honestly don't know how to go about fixing it. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `@import` is quite a way down in the stylesheet. Have you tried adding it at the very start of the css file?

As per [CSS Newbie](http://www.cssnewbie.com/css-import-rule/#.UuAJ9jdFCV5):

> Your @imports must come before all other content in your CSS. And I
>   mean all of your content. Even putting comments before the @import tag
>   will cause your imports to fail. So be sure to do your imports before
>   you do anything else.

See also [this very similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083588/google-fonts-wont-work-when-imported-at-a-less-nested-level) - I've not flagged as a possible duplicate since the other question is specifically about Google Fonts.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use code from CodePen in your own work and/or locally is to download a .zip file of the pen which will give you a full copy of the Pen including the prefixfree.min.js file that you will need to make it work. To do this simply go to the pens page on CodePen and click 'Share' then 'Export.zip' to download the Pen. Unzip the file on your computer and you will have all the files you need to use the code including a licence! P.s I really love these icons!